# Why is my jest "onClick" test not firing the mocked function?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, material-ui

I am using jest to test whether a button is clickable or not. The button is a Material-UI component, but is itself working exactly as intended on the frontend; only the test is failing.

The code for the button:

```
import { Button as BaseButton } from '@mui/material';

export function Button({ children, isDisabled = false, onClick }) {
    return (
        <BaseButton disabled={isDisabled} onClick={onClick}>
            {children}
        </BaseButton>
    );
}
```

And the code for the test:

```
import { Button } from './Button';

import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

it('should be clickable', () => {
        const text = 'Hello World!';
        const testFunction = jest.fn();

        render(<Button onClick={() => testFunction}>{text}</Button>);
        userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Hello World!'));

        expect(testFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

I have other tests in the same file which are passing, so I don't think it's some type of import issue. The button is definitely rendering properly on the test page, but can't be clicked. I have also tried updating the button locator to `userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'));` to no avail.

I am getting the following error from the test file, which I believe is caused by the click test:

```
(node:30870) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to perform pointer interaction as the element has or inherits pointer-events set to "none".
```

However, the button component does not even have a pointer-events property. The child span element, which forms the button label, does have pointer-events: none, but the parent element shouldn't be inheriting that from a child. In addition, I tested the jest.fn() on a normal, html  element and got the exact same error.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually calling the function, just returning it from the `onClick` callback (which doesn't do anything)

```
onClick={() => testFunction}
```

Is the same as:

```
onClick={() => {
  return testFunction;
}}
```

That is just returning testFunction. To call it you want to:

```
onClick={() => testFunction()}
```

Or, if you want to pass it directly so it get's called you can do:

```
onClick={testFunction}
```

Then, when the click fires it will call the passed function. But then it will receive the event arguments etc, which you might not want.